# How do I put items into a const vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I've been trying a bunch of different ways, but I can't figure it out.  The declaration that I was given is:

```
const std::vector<std::string>&,
```

I've been trying to do this:

```
gradeReported.push_back(firstEntry);
```

I keep getting an error.  I am pretty sure it has something to do with the const nature of the vector.  Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't put items into a vector through a `const` ref, because it's `const` (i.e. read-only).  Your only option is to cast away the `const`-ness with `const_cast`, but that's usually inadvisable.

Answer (score 6):

You don't. If it's `const`, it cannot be modified. You need to make a copy or take it by non-const reference.

Comment: Thanks, it seems odd to me that the instructor set these up this way when I was given explicit instructions to change them.

Answer (score 6):

You can't put items into a const vector, the vectors state is the items it holds, and adding items to the vector modifies that state.

If you want to append to a vector you must take in a non const ref.

```
void f(std::vector<int>& v)
{ 
    v.push_back(4);
}
```

Comment: or take the parameter by value

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `const` vector it means you can only read the elements from that vector.
The same rules apply to a vector as to any other type when you use the `const` qualifier.

To be able to modify it, You will either have to make a copy of the original vector or take a non const reference.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a const vector is that you cannot modify it. Appending an element to it would be a modification and thus a violation of its constness. That's why you can't do it. It's by design.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to be able to change it, that's kind of the point of the const. It's mostly used for passing in parameters to functions/methods and having an assurance that it won't be modified.

If you really need to change it, there are two options:

1. Make a copy of the vector and modify that instead.
2. Remove the const via a const_cast.

### Making a copy

```
const std::vector<std::string>& foo;
std::vector<std::string> bar(foo);
```

### Removing const via const_cast

I would strongly recommend against using this, but it is possibly an option.

Assuming that the string vector is being given const protection before being passed as a parameter to a method or a function, and that the underlying type is not actually `const`, then the following can be done:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> string_vector;
void f(const string_vector& foo) {
    const string_vector& foo;
    const_cast<string_vector>(foo).push(firstEntry);
}

int main() {
    string_vector foo();
    f(foo);
}
```

Comment: Removing the `const` via a `const_cast` will only yield a **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: @Als: If using const_cast always resulted in **Undefined Behavior** it wouldn't exist. The comma at the end of the declaration suggests that it is actually a parameter passed in to a function. My hunch is that the parameters is actually modifiable, but has been given const protection.

Comment: Your **hunch** could be costly to someone who doesn't understand the implications of using `const_cast` for casting away the constness, You answer doesn't even explain when the usage is appropriate & when it could lead to an UB.So overall the answer is a poor one.

Comment: My **hunch** is based off standard C++ practices, and this person was clearly given code from someone who knows what they are doing. Your answer, as well as the other top answers, completely ignore what is very likely a valid option and are thus incomplete. If anything, you should be voting down the answers that **don't** mention const_cast.

Comment: @Als: It's only UB if the underlying object really is const.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I very well know that and the answer doesn't say that does it? Hence my comment *, You answer doesn't even explain when the usage is appropriate & when it could lead to an UB.*

Comment: @Als: Ah, fair enough.  I'd only spotted your initial comment.

Comment: @Als: I have to admit, for a guy who wrote an answer in literally under a minute to suggest I have not written enough in this answer is actually kind of insulting.

Comment: I did not insult anyone and the comments are there to see for everyone,If you feel pointing out incorrect information in your answers is insulting then I am sorry I will keep doing that even if you choose to feel insulted.You have aptly demonstrated your revenge tactics by downvoting answers which do not say what you want them to say,It already tells a lot of the situation at hand.I do not wish to be a part of such idiomatic conversations(by virtue of the attitudes invloved)This conversation is over for me.

Comment: @Als: I am sorry that you feel that by voting down answers that were clearly rushed and leave out significant information I am engaging in "revenge". While the information provided in this answer may indeed have been incomplete, I at least made an attempt to provide the full picture.

Comment: Don't use `const_cast`. It violates the interface agreement and the least surprise principle, whether it causes UB or not.

Answer (score -2):

you must remove const in your declaration or if it is impossible use

```
const_cast<std::vector<std::string>& >(gradeReported).push_back(firstEntry);
```

Comment: Is that well defined behaviour then?